# USB Drive with built in WiFi

Tags: usb, wifi, wireless

I am looking for a small (physically) USB drive that will also connect to a wireless network when it's in range. The goal is to have this drive connect to a non-computer device (TV, stereo, car, etc) and be able to play music stored on the device (streaming is not necessary). When it's in range of a preconfigured network, I'd like to be able to access it like any network share.

[SanDisk makes something that is close to my goal](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ZCFYT5K), but has a few disadvantages that I'd like to avoid:

- The use of an app to control data flow
- Physical size of the drive. Ideally, the device would stick out no further than an inch from the USB port it is plugged into. The shorter the better.
- Requires charging the device instead of drawing power via USB (when in Wireless mode)

My criteria:

- Must have at least 8 GB of storage space
- Must connect via WPA2 to a wireless network. Preconfiguration of this network is expected and can occur on a separate computer before the device is plugged into the final system. The final system may not have a way to configure the device (stereo or car).
- Must not stick out further than 1 inch from the USB port it is plugged into
- Must draw power from the device it is plugged into

My budget for this, based on the SanDisk device, is less than $100. However, I am flexible with that, provided the storage capacity of the device is appropriate compared to price.

Comment: Does it have to create a local network folder? It looks like there are some [Seagate wireless hard drives](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/005914en?language=en_US) that can sync via Dropbox or Google Drive. The advantage to that is it could use any wireless network to sync, rather than just your home network.

Comment: I'd prefer to not need to use an app to transfer data. I'm not going to rule out using Google Drive or similar, but the USB device does need to be accessible from a non-computer (ie. A car USB port, or a stereo)